# RoR generated file - When did this happen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hex, hidden-files

[image]

Previously I had been using a different text editor and these .__new_example files were hidden.  Obviously RoR generated some kind of hexadecimal code corresponding to my typed code.

What are they conveying exactly and when do they get generated?

This is more just for the sake of I don't and it drive me nuts not knowing.

Comment: I've not seen anything generated like that before by rails. Are you using any non-standard gems? By non-standard, I mean less than a couple thousand downloads?

Comment: Maybe this? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them

Comment: devise and bootstrap sass is all I changed from default.

Comment: gem 'devise'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
# gem 'unicorn'
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
group :development, :test do
 debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

Comment: You can see [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/2006/Jun/msg00180.html), Matt Deatherage, engineer at Apple, answer to this question and give more explanations about those files. (I have not enough reputations to comment, I am sorry :( )

Comment: hmmm?hmmm?hmmm?hmmm?hmmm?hmmm?hmmm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an apple thing. OS X creates a file for its own purposes.